# How to combine results from a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am selecting data from two tables and want to combine my results. I am currently getting the following results -

```
Sales | Purchase  | ProName      | ProId
0     | 570       | Capital      | 1
2125  | 0         | Capital      | 1
0     | 100       | Bavaria      | 11
587   | 0         | Bavaria      | 11
```

The results I want are -

```
Sales | Purchase  | ProName      | ProId
2125  | 570       | Capital      | 1
587   | 100       | Bavaria      | 11
```

My SQL query is as follows -

```sql
SELECT BillDetails.ProId AS Pro, Products.ProdName AS ProName, Brands.BrandName AS BrName,
SUM(BillDetails.quantity) AS quantity, SUM(IIF(Bills.BillType = 1, quantity, 0)) AS Purchase,
SUM(IIF(Bills.BillType = 2, quantity, 0)) AS Sales
FROM BillDetails
INNER JOIN Products ON (Products.ProductId = BillDetails.ProId)
INNER JOIN Brands ON (Brands.BrandId = BillDetails.brand)
GROUP BY ProId, ProdName, BrandName, BillDetails.BillType
```

Comment: Please try and make your question a little clearer - are you trying to exclude results where either number of sales or purchases is 0?

Comment: Hi Tim , i want add The Sales And The Purchases In the same Row , Without Dublicate The Product Number , I hope Understand What I mean .

Comment: I think I understand what it is you're trying to ask - I have submitted an edit which is awaiting approval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following SQL query will return the results you're after -

```sql
SELECT BillDetails.ProId AS Pro, Products.ProdName AS ProName, Brands.BrandName AS BrName,
SUM(BillDetails.quantity) AS quantity, SUM(IIF(BillDetails.BillType = 1, quantity, 0)) AS Purchase,
SUM(IIF(BillDetails.BillType = 2, quantity, 0)) AS Sales
FROM BillDetails
INNER JOIN Products ON (Products.ProductId = BillDetails.ProId)
INNER JOIN Brands ON (Brands.BrandId = BillDetails.brand)
GROUP BY ProId, ProdName, BrandName
```

You almost had it right, just remove `BillDetails.BillType` from `GROUP BY` - also in your question I noticed you used `IIF(Bills.BillType...` - with the information you provided I assume this should have been `IIF(BillDetails.BillType...`?

Comment: Thank you very much Oliver .  this is what i need . perfect ....the code now work 100 %